# TS interface - Object with any properties

Tags: typescript, interface, properties

How to define interface in TypeScript for object with any properties?

```js
interface Data {
  properties: Properties;
}

interface Properties {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An object with any properties is just like `any`. Why definining an additional interface?
One reason could be, that you want to allow specific value types. Then you can do something like this:

```
interface Properties {
  [key: string]: string|number|boolean;
}
```

Comment: If I do `properties: any;` then it can be any stuff, but I want it to be `Object` with any number of any properties, or to be specific it will be only: Number | Boolean | String. But any number of these properties. Is that possible in TS?

Answer (score 1):

You want the `Record<>` type:

```
interface Data {
  properties: Record<string, number|boolean|string>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for this

```js
type Primitive = string | number | boolean
interface Data {
  [key: string]: Primitive
}

const data1: Data = {
  a: 1,
  b: true,
  c: 'asd'
}

// you basically dont need `Data` interface, instead you can use `Record` as below
const rec: Record<string, Primitive> = data1
```

Comment: Thank you
I was looking for this `[key: string]: `

Comment: Ok, so no I know what is Record in TS, bcs. I was looking for it. TY!

Comment: This is called index types, more info here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-index-signatures